# Representing Date in http header using QDateTime

Tags: qt4, http-headers

HI,

Date in http header is represented according to RFC 822 (As Updated by RFC 1123), like  Wed, 15 Jul 2009 12:16:22 GMT.

Able to represent in QDateTime using

QDateTime testDate = QDateTime::fromString("Wed, 15 Jul 2009 12:16:22","ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");

but without the timezone, wants to represent server time in UTC. Is it possible to specify timezone and get the server time in UTC irrespective of its timezonein Qt?

-Suresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a particular timezone but you can say : ok I want to specify date and time in the current time zone of the machine.
You can get the UTC by QDateTime::toUTC()...I mean convert the local time zone...
But, I'm afraid you can't get the "GMT" by toString() pattern...